# Update from RestKit 0.10 to 0.20

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, restkit, windows-authentication

I'm actually updating my project from ResKit 0.10 to 0.20 and I have an issue. In our web service we use 
Windows Authentication and SSL and if we activate both of them ,RestKit 0.20 is unable to connect. We 
didn't have problems with RestKit 0.10 but with 0.20 we need to desactivate one of them 
(Windows authentication or SSL) to make it work.

I already tried those methods and they didn't work:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:API_USERNAME password:API_PASSWORD];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setDefaultCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:API_USERNAME password:API_PASSWORD persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession]];
```

Is it possible to use RestKit 0.20 with SSL and Windows Authentication? If it's possible, what can 
I do to make it work.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks about right. There have been som bugs in this area. Check that you are using the most up to date version of 0.2x (you might actually want to use the current dev branch if you can till it gets pushed to master).

If you do need to workaround, you can use `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:` to a full operation or you can take the request from `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` and feed it into `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:`.